# How do I print the Images?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I want to print the images of the 30 nba teams drafting in the first round. However when I tell it to print it prints out the link instead of the image. How do I get it to print out the image instead of giving me the image link.
Here's my code:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
# or if your're using BeautifulSoup4:
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.cbssports.com/nba/draft/mock-draft').read())

rows = soup.findAll("table", attrs = {'class': 'data borderTop'})[0].tbody.findAll("tr")[2:]

for row in rows:
  fields = row.findAll("td")
  if len(fields) >= 3:
    anchor = row.findAll("td")[1].find("a")
    if anchor:
      print anchor
```

Comment: How can you print an image? What do you mean "print an image"?

Comment: Browsers load images based on the links given in the HTML source code, with a new connection to the server where the image is located; you will need to do the same.

Comment: Well if you run the code now, it gives me image links. I want to make it so that the code will display the images themselves instead of the image link.

Comment: Wait so what would I do Martjin Pieters

Comment: You can generate a HTML page and open it in browser. What do you think?

Comment: Sorry, but I fear you know too little about how the web works to solve this problem easily in the SO format; start by trying to load the links you find using the same method you loaded the original page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the file into base64 encoding, this will give a string of data that can be moved around and stored if needed. I normally do this with PHP so apologies if the Python is a little rough

```
import urllib2
import base64
url = 'http://somesite.com/images/team_one.jpg'
grab = urllib2.urlopen(url)
encoded_image_string = base64.b64encode(grab.read())
```